# Join two csv files if value is between interval in file 2

Tags: bash, join

I have two csv files that I need to join, F1 has milions of lines, F2 (file 1) has thousands of lines. I need to join these files, if the position in file F1 (F1.pos) is between F2.start and F2.end. Is there any way, how to do this in bash? Because I have a code in Python pandas to sqllite3 and I am looking for something quicker.

Table F1 looks like:

```
| name  | pos   |
|------ |------ |
| a     | 1020  |
| b     | 1200  |
| c     | 1800  |
```

Table F2 looks like:

```
| interval_name     | start     | end   |
|---------------    |-------    |------ |
| int1              | 990       | 1090  |
| int2              | 1100      | 1150  |
| int3              | 500       | 2000  |
```

Result should look like:

```
| name  | pos   | interval_name     | start     | end   |
|------ |------ |---------------    |-------    |------ |
| a     | 1020  | int1              | 990       | 1090  |
| a     | 1020  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
| b     | 1200  | int1              | 990       | 1090  |
| b     | 1200  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
| c     | 1800  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
```

Comment: I can't help but feel it would be quicker to import this into sqlite as-is and do your complex join in the database. This data is big enough to warrant it.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, your input files are not CSV (Comma Separated Values)

Comment: If what you've posted as sample input/poutput is a tabular representation of your real files - don't do that. We need something we can test a potential solution against. Post a few lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output in your **real** file format.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a bash script would be faster than a python script. Just don't import the files into a database – write a custom join function instead!

The best way to join depends on your input data. If nearly all `F1.pos` are inside of nearly all intervals then a naive approach would be the fastest. The naive approach in bash would look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
join --header -t, -j99 F1 F2 |
sed 's/^,//' |
awk -F, 'NR>1 && $2 >= $4 && $2 <= $5'
# NR>1 is only there to skip the column headers
```

However, this will be very slow if there are only a few intersections, for instance, when the average `F1.pos` only is in 5 intervals. In this case the following approach will be way faster. Implement it in a programing language of your choice – bash is not appropriate for this:

- Sort F1 by `pos` in ascending order.
- Sort F2 by `start` and then by `end` in ascending order.
- For each sorted file, keep a pointer to a line, starting at the first line.
- Repeat until F1's pointer reaches the end:

  - For the current `F1.pos` advance F2's pointer until `F1.pos` ≥ `F2.start`.
  - Lock F2's pointer, but continue to read lines until `F1.pos` ≤ `F2.end`. Print the read lines in the output format `name,pos,interval_name,start,end`.
  - Advance F1's pointer by one line.

Only sorting the files could be actually faster in bash. Here is a script to sort both files.

```
#! /bin/bash
sort -t, -n -k2 F1-without-headers > F1-sorted
sort -t, -n -k2,3 F2-without-headers > F2-sorted
```

Consider using `LC_ALL=C`, `-S N%` and `--parallel N` to speed up the sorting process.

Answer (score 0):

#### DISCLAIMER: Use dedicated/local tools if available, this is hacking:

There is an apparent error in your desired output: name `b` should not match `int1`.

```
$ tail -n+1 *.csv
==> f1.csv <==
name,pos
a,1020
b,1200
c,1800

==> f2.csv <==
interval_name,start,end
int1,990,1090
int2,1100,1150
int3,500,2000

$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '
  BEGIN {
    print "name,pos,interval_name,start,end"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
  }
  FNR==1 {next}
  NR==FNR {Int[$1] = $2 "," $3; next}
  {
    for(i in Int) {
      split(Int[i], I)
      if($2 >= I[1] && $2 <= I[2]) print $0, i, Int[i]
    }
  }
' f2.csv f1.csv
```

Outputs:

```
name,pos,interval_name,start,end
a,1020,int1,990,1090
a,1020,int3,500,2000
b,1200,int3,500,2000
c,1800,int3,500,2000
```

This is not particularly efficient in any way; the only sorting used is to ensure that the Int array is parsed in the correct order, which changes if your sample data is not indicative of the actual schema. I would be very interested to know how my solution performs vs pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk. It hashes the smaller file records to arrays and for each of the bigger file records it iterates thru the hashes so it is slow:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                             # hash f2 records
    start[NR]=$4
    end[NR]=$6
    data[NR]=substr($0,2)
    next
}
FNR<=2 {                              # mind the front matter
    print $0 data[FNR]
}
{                                     # check if in range and output
    for(i in start)
        if($4>start[i] && $4<end[i])
            print $0 data[i]
}' f2 f1
```

Output:

```
| name  | pos   | interval_name     | start     | end   |
|------ |------ |---------------    |-------    |------ |
| a     | 1020  | int1              | 990       | 1090  |
| a     | 1020  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
| b     | 1200  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
| c     | 1800  | int3              | 500       | 2000  |
```